# React - How to access passed props object name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react, if I have a component that looks something along the lines of this:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    return stuff
}
```

and I pass in props like this:

```
<SomeComponent foo={"x"}/>
```

How can I get the props object name of `foo` from the props within the component?
For example, so that I can use it in a function like:

```
const useObjectName = (xyz) => {
  if (xyz){
    //do something 
  }
}
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const theObjectName = ???
  useObjectName(theObjectName)
  return stuff
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) but `Object.keys(props)`

Comment: you could've received relevant code samples along with some meaningful comments, should you post some *real* code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thanks, building on that got me to where I needed to be.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Apologies for the rushed question.

Comment: Simply by doing `props.foo` you can access `foo` inside the SomeComponent. Could you please elaborate on the question if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik the question was asking how to access the object name, not the object value. Guy has answered the question in this comment thread.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using `Object.keys(props)` which will return `["foo"]`.